# Datawedge intent package for react native not working

Tags: android, react-native, npm, barcode-scanner, datawedge

I want to read data from barcode in a react native application android and I have Zebra TC26, the package i have used was react-native-datawedge-intent but can't get success, Can you please guide me further so that I can acheive the requirement?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_reproducible_example#:~:text=In%20computing%2C%20a%20minimal%20reproducible,to%20be%20demonstrated%20and%20reproduced.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.